# Using Mobiscroll with webpack and babel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, webpack, mobiscroll

I am using Mobiscroll from their [github](https://github.com/acidb/mobiscroll) but I have also tried using their generator with [react](https://download.mobiscroll.com/trialactivatedsuccess#/calendar/).

The problem with the github version is it comes as multiple files:

```
bower_components/mobiscroll/js/mobiscroll.android-holo-light.js
bower_components/mobiscroll/js/mobiscroll.core.js
bower_components/mobiscroll/js/mobiscroll.dom.js
bower_components/mobiscroll/js/mobiscroll.frame.android-holo.js
bower_components/mobiscroll/js/mobiscroll.frame.ios.js
bower_components/mobiscroll/js/mobiscroll.frame.jqm.js
bower_components/mobiscroll/js/mobiscroll.frame.js
bower_components/mobiscroll/js/mobiscroll.frame.wp.js
bower_components/mobiscroll/js/mobiscroll.mobiscroll-dark.js
bower_components/mobiscroll/js/mobiscroll.scroller.js
bower_components/mobiscroll/js/mobiscroll.scrollview.js
bower_components/mobiscroll/js/mobiscroll.wp-light.js
```

So how am I meant to approch this from a import point of view when clearly in the [react documention](https://demo.mobiscroll.com/v3/react/calendar) it says:

> ```
> var CalendarDemo = React.createClass({
>     render: function() {
>         return (
>             <div>
>                 <MobiscrollCalendar 
>                     ref="calendar" 
>                     theme="mobiscroll" 
>                     display="bottom"
>                     placeholder="Please Select..."
>                 />
>             </div>
>         );
>     }    
> });
>
> ReactDOM.render(
>     <CalendarDemo />,
>     document.getElementById('content')
> );
> ```

I cannot find a clear way to get: MobiscrollCalendar out of these files.

So I think I am safe in assume that the github version is not intended for webpack.

**react & weback safe version** - So I am led to believe :)

I did try the bundled version which is exclusively for react and I have been told supports webpack.

**Js file**

```
import {MobiscrollCalendar} from '../../lib/mobiscroll';

class Home extends React.Component {
    render = function (){
        return (
            <app-content>
                <Header />
                <div className={loggedOut.home}>
                    <MobiscrollCalendar
                        ref="calendar"
                        theme="mobiscroll"
                        display="bottom"
                        placeholder="Please Select..."
                    />
                </div>
            </app-content>
        )
    }
}
```

However using this gives me the following **error**:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

So to get round this issue, which goes against me using webpack :) was to add wreact and mobiscroll into the html:

```
<script src="/js/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/mobiscroll.js"></script>
<script src="/js/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Which then results in the following **error**

```
warning.js:44 Warning: getInitialState was defined on t, a plain JavaScript class. This is only supported for classes created using React.createClass. Did you mean to define a state property instead?
warning.js:44 Warning: Unknown DOM property readonly. Did you mean readOnly?
```

I believe I will give up now. :( I am unsure how others could help.